# como hacer que un metodo se siga ejecutando todo el tiempo tanto dentro como afuera de la aplicacion en flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-auth

Buenas tardes estoy usando flutter y firebase para este proyecto quiero que el metodo llamado validaciondehora se puede ejecutar en todo momento dentro y fuera de la aplicacion como haria para que ese metodo siga haciendo si tarea sin necesidad de entrar a la pestaña

creia que usando este metodo en el controlador y poniendolo enel init me daria esa solucion pero no entonces era para ver que solucion me pueden vrindar para esto

````
class ListademedicaNController extends GetxController {
//Variables y Listas
  RxList<Medicamentos> medicamentos = RxList<Medicamentos>([]);
  List<Medicamentos> get medicamentosget => medicamentos;
  late Stream<List<Medicamentos>> medicamentosStream;
  RxBool isloading = false.obs;
  String hoy = DateFormat('hh:mm').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
  String fechalimite =
      DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
  Pacientes? paciente;
// Inicializar metodos
  @override
  void onInit() {
    paciente = Get.arguments['id'];
    medicamentosStream = getmedico();
    super.onInit();
    init();
  }

  getmedico() => medicamentoservices
      .obtenerlistmedicamentos()
      .where("idpaciente", isEqualTo: paciente!.id)
      .snapshots()
      .map((event) => event.docs.map((e) => Medicamentos.fromJson(e)).toList());

  init() {
    medicamentosStream.listen((event) async {
      medicamentos.value = event;
      validaciondehora(event);
    });
  }

 void validaciondehora(List<Medicamentos> event) async {
    for (var i in event) {
      if (i.fechaExpiracion == fechalimite) {
        break;
      } else {
        if (i.hora == hoy) {
          notificaionees.shownotify(
              id: 0,
              title: i.nombreM!,
              body: (('''Dosis: ${i.dosis!}'''
                      "\n") +
                  ('''Hora: ${i.hora}'''
                      "\n")),
              payload: "");
        }
      }
    }
  }
} ```
````

Comment: No entiendo ni papa del problema. ¿Puedes replantearlo de otra forma? ¿Qué quieres decir con dentro y fuera de la aplicación? ¿Y a qué te refieres con sin necesidad de entrar a la pestaña?